# How to type in hindi in ckeditor

Tags: ckeditor

I am using ckeditor in my website.I want to know how can I type in hindi in ckeditor.I am using kruti dev010.
in config.js file I have included:

```
config.font_names = 'kruti_dev_010;' + config.font_names;
```

and in content.css file I have added:

```
@font-face {
    font-family:'kruti_dev_010regular';
    src: url('krutidev-webfont.eot');
    src: url('krutidev-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('krutidev-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
    url('krutidev-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('krutidev-webfont.svg#kruti_dev_010bold') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

I am not able to type in hindi and if I paste the content from word it is displaying some special character

Comment: i also want solution...for this

Answer (score -1):

Download hindi font Kruti010 fonts [here](http://indiatyping.com/index.php/download/95-hindi-font-krutidev).

Add this in `Config.js` of `CkEditor`:

```
config.font_names = 'Hindi/Kruti'; + config.font_names;
```

add hindi fonts in `Ckeditor`'s langs folder:

```
ckeditor/lang/Kruti/k010.ttf
```

add css in content.css of ckeditor.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Kruti';
    src: url('lang/Kruti/k010.eot');
    src: local("Hindi"), url("lang/Kruti/k010.ttf") format("truetype");
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    }
```

check your path properly.